# move images in a line with timed effect

Tags: jquery, css, image, jquery-animate, move

the idea is that I have a div with some images ( in a horizontal line) you only see the first image within the div.
For now there are 5 images.
I want to move the images from right to left leaving the div (and screen) and after the last images has moved the first image will be in front  (that is 1 entire loop)
to start the animation, you click a button.

now the trick of this, at every uneven numbered image the animation has to stop a few moments. so the starting image is 1, then pass number 2 and stop at 3 for a few seconds then pass numver 4 and stop at number 5 after that the image continues to the first one again and stops until start button is clicked again.

I want to be able to expand the amount of images fairly easy.

what I have so far in CSS / HTMl is

```
<body>

<div id="container">


    <div id="fotos">
        <div class="image"><img src="afb_stuk/1.png"/></div>
        <div class="image"><img src="afb_stuk/2.png"/></div>
        <div class="image"><img src="afb_stuk/3.png"/></div>

        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>



</div>
<div id="start">
    <h2 class="text"></h2>
</div>
</body>
```

and css

```
body{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
background-image:url(afb_stuk/background.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;}


#container{
position:relative;
margin-left:50px;
margin-top:25px;
height:600px;
width:1250px;
border:solid thin red;
z-index:1;
/*overflow:hidden;*/}


#fotos{
position:relative;
height:80%;
width:12000px;}


.image{
height:600px;
width:1250px;
float: left;


.image img{
height:600px;
width:auto;}


#start{
position:relative;
margin:auto;
margin-top:-10px;
height:10px;
width:60px;

border-radius: 25px;
border: 2px solid #8AC007;
padding: 20px; }



.text{
margin-top:-10px;}
```

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle of your code including your current jquery?

Comment: No I do not, I dont have any Jquery code yet. TRying some things but still learning how it works and having quite some problems with it :(

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function start()
    {
    var y=1;
    var x=document.getElementById("image");
    setInterval(function(){check();},1000);
    function check()
    {
        if(y%2!=0)
            {
                setTimeout(function(){},3000);
            }
            x.src=''+(y%6)+'.jpg'+'';
        y++;
            if(y==6)
            start();
        }
    }
    </script>
    <style>
    body{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    background-image:url(afb_stuk/background.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;}


    #container{
    position:relative;
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-top:25px;
    height:600px;
    width:1250px;
    border:solid thin red;
    z-index:1;
    /*overflow:hidden;*/}


    #fotos{
    position:relative;
    height:80%;
    width:12000px;}


    .image{
    height:600px;
    width:1250px;
    float: left;
    }

    .image img{
    height:600px;
    width:auto;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="fotos">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="1.jpg" id="image"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="start()" id="new">Click to start!</button> 
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

your image names should be in form of 1,2,3,4.jpg etc.
and try to accumulate the delay between images.

Comment: thnx. It is not working yet though but wil post when Ive got it working
edit: have to put every image in his own div class box then it works but it is not sliding yet

Answer (score 0):

i have found a very good youtube tutorial including a fiddle.
I just changed some of the effects (and image width) to giv it the effect I liked and wanted.
Thnx to all who have helped me :)
[1]http://jsfiddle.net/EjZzs/15/

```
$(function() {

//settings for slider
var width = 720;
var animationSpeed = 1000;
var pause = 3000;
var currentSlide = 1;

//cache DOM elements
var $slider = $('#slider');
var $slideContainer = $('.slides', $slider);
var $slides = $('.slide', $slider);

var interval;

function startSlider() {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width}, animationSpeed, function() {
            if (++currentSlide === $slides.length) {
                currentSlide = 1;
                $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
            }
        });
    }, pause);
}
function pauseSlider() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}

$slideContainer
    .on('mouseenter', pauseSlider)
    .on('mouseleave', startSlider);

startSlider();
```

});

[2]https://youtu.be/KkzVFB3Ba_o